# How to fix Windows boot after grub installed?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, grub2, dualboot

I had a laptop running Windows 10, quite nicely. I used an Ubuntu installer to try and install a dual-boot system. When it asked me if I wanted to let it install grub in the boot record, I pointedly said no.

It did it anyway. On the next boot, grub came up, with no evident way of booting to Windows. A friend who doesn't live nearby so I can't ask him all the time, worked on the problem for a while and came up with a hackish method:

1. At the boot menu, choose "Start EFI shell"
2. There type: fs2:\efi\microsoft\boot\bootmgfw.efi

I don't speak that language, I don't understand how that file system reference translates into regular Linux or regular Windows. But hopefully someone here does? In particular is it possible to configure grub to do that?

Or, how to "put back" the original Windows boot situation without having to reinstall Windows from scratch? My existing Windows installation has apps that I no longer have the permission to install, so it would be really valuable for me not to have to start over.

Not to mention, for future reference, what would be a better way to install this dual-boot situation that I'm looking for?